# How to create staging table to handle incremental load

Tags: data-warehouse

We are designing a `Staging layer` to handle `incremental load`. I want to start with a simple scenario to design the `staging`.

In the source database There are two tables ex, tbl_Department, tbl_Employee. Both this table is loading a single table at destination database ex, tbl_EmployeRecord.

The query which is loading tbl_EmployeRecord is,

```
SELECT EMPID,EMPNAME,DEPTNAME 
FROM tbl_Department D 
INNER JOIN tbl_Employee E 
ON D.DEPARTMENTID=E.DEPARTMENTID
```

Now, we need to identify incremental load in tbl_Department, tbl_Employee and store it in staging and load only the incremental load to the destination.

The columns of the tables are,

- tbl_Department : DEPARTMENTID,DEPTNAME
- tbl_Employee : EMPID,EMPNAME,DEPARTMENTID
- tbl_EmployeRecord : EMPID,EMPNAME,DEPTNAME

Kindly suggest how to design the staging for this to handle Insert, Update and Delete.

Answer (score 3):

**Identifying Incremental Data**

The incremental loading needs to be based on some segregating information present in your source table. Such information helps you to identify the incremental portion of the data that you will load. Often times, load date or last updated date of the record is a good choice for this.

Consider this, your source table has a date column that stores both the date of insertion of the records as well as the date when any update was done on that record. At any given day during your staging load, you may take advantage of this date to identify which are the records that are newly inserted or updated since your last staging load and you consider only those changed / updated records as your incremental delta.

Given your structure of the tables, I am not sure which column you may use for this. ID columns will not help as if the record gets updated you won't know that.

**Maintaining Load History**

It is important to store information about how much you have loaded today so that you can load the next part in the next load. To do this, maintain a staging table - often called `Batch Load Details` table. That load typically will have structure such as below:

```
BATCH ID | START DATE | END DATE  | LOAD DATE | STATUS
------------------------------------------------------
1        | 01-Jan-14  | 02-Jan-14 | 02-Jan-14 | Success
```

You need to insert a new record in this table everyday before you start the data loading. The new record will have start date equal to the end date of last successful load and status null. Once loading is successful, you will update the status to 'Success'

**Modification in data Extraction Query to take Advantage of Batch Load Table**

Once you maintain your loading history like above, you may include this table in your extraction query,

```
SELECT EMPID,EMPNAME,DEPTNAME 
FROM tbl_Department D 
INNER JOIN tbl_Employee E 
ON D.DEPARTMENTID=E.DEPARTMENTID
WHERE E.load_date >= (SELECT max(START_DATE) FROM BATCH_LOAD WHERE status IS NULL)
```

What I am going suggest you is by no means a standard. In fact you should evaluate my suggestion carefully against your requirement.

**Suggestion**

Use incremental loading for transaction data, not for master data. Transaction data are generally higher in volume and can be easily segregated in incremental chunks. Master data tend to be more manageable and can be loaded in Full everytime. In the above example, I am assuming your Employee table is behaving like transactional data whereas your department table is your master.

I trust [this article on incremental loading](https://dwbi.org/pages/75/methods-of-incremental-loading-in-data-warehouse) will be very helpful for you

Comment: The article link is broken

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what database you are using, so I'll just talk in conceptual terms. If you want to add tags for specific technologies, we can probably provide specific advice.

It looks like you have 1 row per employee and that you are only keeping the current record for each employee. I'm going to assume that EMPIDs are unique.

First, add a field to the query that currently populates the dimension.  This field will be a hash of the other fields in the table EMPID, EMPNAME, DEPTNAME. You can create a view, populate a new staging table, or just use the query. Also add this same hash field to the dimension table. Basically, the hash is an easy way to generate a field that is unique for each record and efficient to compare.

**Inserts:** These are the records for which the EMPID does not already exist in the dimension table but does exist in your staging query/view.

**Updates:** These are the records for which the EMPID *does* in both the staging query/view the dimension table, but the hash field doesn't match.

**Deletes:** These are the records for which the EMPID exists in the dimension but does not exist in the staging query/view.

If this will be high-volume, you may want to create new tables to hold the records that should be inserted and the records that should be updated. Once you have identified the records, you can insert/update them all at once instead of one-by-one.

It's a bit uncommon to delete lots of records from a data warehouse as they are typically used to keep history. I would suggest perhaps creating a column that is a status or a bit field that indicates if is is active or deleted in the source. Of course, how you handle deletes should be dependent upon your business needs/reporting requirements. Just remember that if you do a hard delete you can never get that data back if you decide you need it later.

Updating the the existing dimension in place (rather than creating historical records for each change) is called a Type 1 dimension in dimensional modeling terms. This is fairly common. But if you decide you need to keep history, you can use the hash to help you create the SCD type 2 records.

Comment: @Jim You might want to edit your view into the question rather than posting your comments as an answer.